# multiple user logins in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am using jmeter to test a php application. I need to create a different thread with a unique session for each user. Because in my application you can only have one login per user at a time so putting 100 times the same user I will not get to any conclusion.
I have created 40 users user0,user1....user39 with the same password is there a way to automatically create simultaneous threads for each of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a CSV Data Set Config. This control will allow you to use an external source of variables. 
Add -> Config Element -> CSV Data Set Config
You must set the variable names, something like:
Variable Names (comma-delimited): USERNAME,PASSWORD

Then you can use the variables in your HTTP Requests parameters like:
${USERNAME} and ${PASSWORD}

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll check out if/how it works and I'll give you the acceptance vote ;)

Comment: See also http://jmeter-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/tip-10-how-to-add-authorization-to-test.html

Answer (score 62):

I just implemented this using jmeter for an app that uses Spring Security (It would be very similar to PHP). This is fairly straightforward, basically:

1) Create a new CSV file using a text editor
   Ex: CSVSample_user.csv

```
   username1, password1
   username2, password2
```

2) In jmeter, create a CSV Data Set Config element

```
  Thread Group>add>Config Element>CSV Data Set Config
  => Assign variable names (see image)
```

3) Create an HTTP Request element

```
  Thread Group>add>Sampler>HTTP Request
  => Create a POST with parameters, have the variable you created 
     put the values for the parameter. (See bottom image).
```

NOTE: There are other elements you need, such as cookie manager, etc. Also number of threads needs to be set to the number of login users.

[image]

Answer (score 28):

I realize this question is over a year old, but I just came across the same issue and thought I'd add my solution for anyone else who stumbles upon this issue.

If you have a sequence of usernames and passwords that are simply differentiated by numbers at the end of their values, you can use the __threadNum variable to log them in. So for the value of username you might say user${__threadNum}.

This solution is simpler than including a csv but only works where you have a list such as the one you suggested in your question.

Comment: You can combine `${__threadNum}` together with beanshell or javascript `switch` statements. This will overcome the "seqeuence only" limitation because in the switch itself you could basically replace the value with anything.

Answer (score 1):

keep csv file and testplan (i.e jmx) in a same folder and recheck the variable name in CSV datasetconfig and http request for any typing error.