# how to multiple users login and logout in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

300 users Login the site.
300 users used to create the business process.
300 users logout the site.

what are the controllers and samplers need?

I have tried some of the my own examples. But i did not get the solution. Someone give the solution briefly.

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: Duplicate - someone answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623489/multiple-user-logins-in-jmeter

Comment: Thanks for your reply...! I have already followed your mentioned link. But i can't the solution. when i pass wrong userid and password through csv file. It is also accepted. No error has been raised. How i finalize the passing user id and password are correct or not?

Comment: To raise the error, did you do anything in JMeter? JMeter passes/fails the response based on the HTTP codes.

Comment: Hi Vinoth..! thanks.. I did not received any error. so that only i m confusing. if it is raise the error, i m understand. But did not.

Comment: Hi All. shall i know how to identify the authentication informations are passed or not? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing a web application, follow these steps:

1. Record the workflow

Use the HTTP(S) test script recorder to record all the requests. Follow the steps [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
or you can manually add the required HTTP Request samplers.

2. Parameterize your script

For example,in your case you can parameterize the users using CSV data set config.Refer [this](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1740850-using-csv-data-set-config).

3. Correlation

For correlation, i.e. fetching a value from the previous response that is used by the current request,use Regular expression extractor(post processor).Refer [this link](http://sjpknight.com/correlating-dynamic-values-in-jmeter/)

You can add the 'View Results Tree'Listener and execute the test plan to check the requests/response and validate your script.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get distribution of 300 for login/ 300 for BP / 300 for logout the best option is to use [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller). See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) guide for details.
2. To conditionally fail sampler basing on this or that criteria you can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion). JMeter automatically considers 2xx and 3xx HTTP response codes successful, even if response says "Failed to log in" so you can use Response Assertion to ensure that response contains some piece of text specific for logged in user or something