# How to access CSV using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

---

Let us consider we have an excel/csv containing multiple columns, column1 contains the website and the other columns contain the parameters, how to perform http GET login and map parameters of each site and get the result sheet in jmeter. Can someone help in solving this issue....

### Thanks...

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10745233/4324778) answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

you can map columns of the csv file with [CSV_Data_Set_Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) 
by setting variables names to : url,user,pwd.

after that you can use them on another components like this `'${user}'`

do http request [HTTP_Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

and save the result with [Save_Responses_to_a_file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) or to see them [View_Results_Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)